# Place order Insert custom field value in sales_order or quote table using plugin

Tags: magento2, plugin

I want to insert custom field value in sales_order or quote table order place time using plugin.

**`THANKS.`**

Comment: do you want this before place order or after place order?

Comment: Yes, I want to before place order @Dhiren Vasoya

Comment: Then usethe observer.

Comment: i want to plugin

Comment: I post the answer, with plugin, you can use After, around plugin for same method according to your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

You can create before Order place plugin like this one :

1. create `di.xml` file in this `app\code\Vendor\Extension\etc\di.xml` with this code.

   ```
   <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
      <type name="Magento\Sales\Model\Order">
          <plugin name="vendor_extension_order_before_plugin" type="Vendor\Extension\Plugin\Orderplugin" sortOrder="10" disabled="false"  />
      </type>
   </config>
   ```
2. now create `Orderplugin.php` at following location `app\code\Vendor\Extension\Plugin\Orderplugin.php`

   ```
   <?php

   namespace Vendor\Extension\Plugin;

   class Orderplugin
   {

       public function beforePlace(\Magento\Sales\Model\Order $subject)
       {
           // Write Your logic 
       }

   }
   ```

Comment: i will check your answer But this method working quote and sales_order filed value insert place order time ?

Comment: The method it self creating the order, and you need to put your logic into this one.